# Responsive Website Content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The design for the mobile sized browser is very different from the design for the full screen browser. i have come up with a solution that does work (display:none;) but is that a good way to do it? should i be doing something else?

```
@media only screen
and (max-width:480px){
#image01{
    /* sizing and positioning etc*/
    display:none;
}
#image02{
    /* sizing and positioning etc*/
}
h1#big{
    /*sizing and positioning etc */
    display:none;
}
h1#small{
    /*sizing and positioning etc */
}
@media only screen
and (min-width:992px){
#image01{
    /* sizing and positioning etc*/
}
#image02{
    /* sizing and positioning etc*/
    display:none;
}
h1#big{
    /*sizing and positioning etc */
}
h1#small{
    /*sizing and positioning etc */
    display:none;
}



<div id="image01">
    <img src="image01.jpg" alt="image01" />
</div>
<div id="image02">
    <img src="image02.jpg" alt="image02" />
</div>
<h1 id="big">Big header</h1>
<h1 id="small">Small header</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `display: none` to hide content from smaller screens as it’s seen as a lazy approach.

Also, it’s bad from a performance point of view because your users still download this content, despite it being visibly hidden.

Comment: thats what i thought however research has only identified max-width:100%; width:100%; as a solution. i have tried this:  div#image01{
  /*positioning*/
  max-width:50%;
  min-width:5%;
  width:auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  height:auto; 
 }

Comment: but cant get it to resize with browser. ps sorry about the messy broken commets it wouldnt let me type properly :/

Comment: If it’s an image and you’re wanting it to be as wide as the viewport, then add `img { max-width: 100%; }`. If you’re crafting a *significantly* different site for mobile users then I’d suggest media queries may not be the way to go and a native app or dedicated mobile site may be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: the max-width doesnt seem to do anything at all though? am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Sorry, typo in my previous comment and can’t edit it. I meant to say: you *shouldn’t* be using `max-width: 100%` and `width: 100%` in conjunction with each other.

Comment: I was under the understanding you should use max-width:100%; but this doesnt work in ie so you should add width:100%; so works in any?

Comment: You can use `width` and `max-width` in conjunction with each other only if they’re different units, otherwise you’re saying “display this image 100% of its width and a maximum of 100% of its width” which is always going to be the same. See http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/max-width for more on the `max-width` property.

Comment: i figured out why it wasnt working btw doh!!! - i had to set div#image01{ width: so much %;} and then div#image01 img{max-width:100%;} - it now works and has flexible sizing without having to have two diff sized images :) thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

*some* elements that simply will not look right on a mobile device should be hidden like this. However in most cases everything can be either resized, moved or minimised with the ability to maximise with a tap (like menus).

[Give this a read for more tips](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/guidelines-for-mobile-web-development/)

Answer (score 0):

Unless those images are part of the content, you should load them as background images.  Then you control which image is loaded within your media queries

```
@media only screen
and (max-width:480px){
#image01{
    /* sizing and positioning etc*/
    background-image:none;
}
}

@media only screen
and (max-width:992px){
#image01{
    /* sizing and positioning etc*/
    background-image:url('path/to/image');
}
}
```